# How to assert that a method's variable is set to the right class instance using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

This python method sets the 'registrar' variable to an instance of one of two classes (Registrar1 and Registrar2 just for illustration) based on the tld of the provided domain. Then returns the execution of the corresponding class's is_available() method.

I need to create a pytest that checks the 'registrar' variable from this method is effectively being set to Registrar1 or Registrar2 based on the test string (aka domain) passed inside pytest.

The method's script is:

```
def domain_is_available(domain: str, ip_rotate: bool = False) -> bool:
    """
    Factory-like function helping to quickly determine if a domain is available or not, without caring about the registrar
    """
    domain = get_domain(domain)
    if domain.endswith(".jp"):
        registrar = Registrar1(ip_rotate=ip_rotate)
    else:
        registrar = Registrar2(ip_rotate=ip_rotate)

    return registrar.is_available(domain)
```

I tried myself with pytest and MonkeyPatch but couldn't get to the desired outcome. I also asked GPT but it fails to provide a solution that incorporates the fact that domain_is_available() returns the result of the is_available() method from either Registrar1 or Registrar2 class. The is_available() method only returns a True or False boolean value based on whether the received domain is available or not. It does not return the 'registrar' object on itself (or an instance).

How can I mock this variable? I understand it can not be directly asserted (perhaps it is possible?) as it is not being directly returned.

I would be very thankful if anyone can help me out on this one. Perhaps I failed to implement either pytest on itself or MonkeyPatch specifically. Please let me know if this post needs clarifying or more details. I appreciate any feedback.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you able to mock or spy on Registrar1 and  Registrar2 then confirm the correct method is called?

Comment: No I can't spy on it when executing the domain_is_available() method. Regarding mocking the classes themselves, that's an approach I haven't tried. So far i just tried to mock the 'registrar' variable but I think I am not understanding the mechanics correctly

Comment: you can't mock a local variable, and there is no way to really test what you want to do here, tests shouldn't concern themselves with these sorts of implementation details anyway

Comment: If you really want to test it, then refactor the logic into a function that simply returns the correct `Registrar` object, then call that function in `def domain_is_available`, then test the function you've refactored out

Comment: Yeah, that is what I've been coming to understand. But wanted to make sure by asking the community. I was thinking about the refactor thing yesterday. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Would it be possible to mock it though? My guess is no, since it cant be directly tested but it's worth to ask

Comment: @Alvaro: You should be able to mock everything. In case you can't (or is a hassle to mock) you need to refactor the (poorly written) codebase.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) `is_available` (here using a decorator) for both `Registrar`'s.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock


def get_domain(domain):
    return domain


class Registrar:

    def __init__(self, ip_rotate):
        pass

    def is_available(self, domain):
        return True


Registrar1 = Registrar2 = Registrar


def domain_is_available(domain: str, ip_rotate: bool = False) -> bool:
    """
    Factory-like function helping to quickly determine if a domain is available or not, without caring about the registrar
    """
    domain = get_domain(domain)
    if domain.endswith(".jp"):
        registrar = Registrar1(ip_rotate=ip_rotate)
    else:
        registrar = Registrar2(ip_rotate=ip_rotate)

    return registrar.is_available(domain)


class Test_001(unittest.TestCase):
    # Mock to return False!!
    @mock.patch.object(Registrar1, 'is_available', return_value=False)
    @mock.patch.object(Registrar2, 'is_available', return_value=False)
    def test_domain_is_available(self, mock_obj1, mock_obj2):
        for d in ('google.jp', 'yahoo.com'):
            self.assertFalse(domain_is_available(d))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Out:

```
python3 /tmp/x.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I need to perform is to check what class registrar is an instance of (Registrar1 or Registrar2), not to test the returning value of domain_is_available